# Read each line from a file and if that line length is smaller than 9 add that line to an array

Tags: python

```
words = []
    for line in f:
        if len(line) <= 9:
            words.append(line)
        #words = f.readlines(250000)
    f.close()
    return words
```

I am trying to read each line from a text file which contains one word. I want to be able to compare the length of that word to a condition and if it meets that condition then add it to a list to save the words that are under 9 characters long. The code should go through the entire file and the words that are under 9 characters should be added to the array called words. I tried using `f.readlines()`but I dont know how to filter the results as this just gives all of the words in the file.

Comment: what is the problem ? Code seems OK. Maybe except that `line` mostly has `"\n"` at the end which you should remove - `line = line.rstrip()`

Comment: if you what to use `readlines()` then you also have to use `for`-loop - like `for line in f.readlines():`. Eventually list comprehension - `words = [line for line in f.readlines() if len(line) <= 9]` - but lines will have '"\n"' at the end. Eventually `words = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines() if len(line.rstrip()) <= 9]`

Comment: There wasn't any error message its just that python stopped responding when this line of code started to execute

Comment: How are you running your code? Do you have this saved in a file? Or are you entering this directly into the Python interpreter?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am using the Python IDLE to run to code

Comment: if file is big then it may take time to run it and you could print some information from time to time - ie. print dot or number every 100 lines. OR maybe you get error which you didn't see and it doesn't run at all. ie. if you don't have this code in function then you shouldn't use `return` because it can get error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `file.readlines` as this:

```py
with open('path/to/file') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if len(line.strip()) <= 9:
            words.append(line)
```

see that using context manager to open file is a good practice so you also dont need to close it at the end and you wont forget to :)

Comment: What happens when python stops responding? Do I just have to wait for it to respond? In your solution and in my solution python stops responding.

Comment: @AmrikAhluwalia How long is this file?

Comment: @AmrikAhluwalia You could add some print statements to see if python is doing anything. For example, `print(line)` inside of your loop. Also, if you want to force the python script to stop, you can press Ctrl-C.

Comment: @Reznik There are 235887 lines according to the code I wrote earlier which counted the lines.

Comment: @AmrikAhluwalia well its a big file, i guess it take a bit of a time to go thru all those line

Comment: @AmrikAhluwalia Sounds like you just need to wait longer. That large of a file will take some time to process.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Its worked to a degree as the words have been sorted and shown however it's still doing something and the /n haven't been stripped from the strings?